# How to prevent users from renaming files while providing write permissions on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, shell, permissions

For some special purpose, I want to prevent non-root users of the Linux Server from changing the filenames. However, they can modify and write to the contents of the file. How to do this from command line.

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93399/how-to-prevent-users-from-renaming-files-while-providing-write-permissions-on-li; please don't post on multiple sites simultaneously!

Comment: Also, what is that "special purpose" (it might help getting better answers), and what have to found / tried?!

Comment: Also cross posted at http://askubuntu.com/questions/353054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as root:

```
> mkdir -m 0755 testdir
> touch testdir/testfile
> chmod 0666 testdir/testfile
```

as guest:

```
> echo test > testdir/testfile
> mv testdir/testfile testdir/foobar
mv: cannot move `testdir/testfile' to `testdir/foobar': Permission denied
```

Works for me.